# doubt regarding use of split in awk

Tags: awk

```
arr=($(echo "great#man" | awk  '{split($0,a,"#"); } END {print a[0]; print a[1];}')) 
    echo " ${arr[0]} "
    echo " ${arr[1]}"
```

My expected output is:

```
great
man
```

But I am getting

```
great
```

arr[1] is not getting printed

Comment: You don't need `split` here. `echo "great#man" | awk -F# 'END {print $1; print $2;}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variation works for me:

```
$ echo "great#man" | awk '{split($0,a,"#"); } END {print a[1]; print a[2];}'
great
man
```

From the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions):

```
split(string, array [, fieldsep [, seps ] ])
```

> Divide string into pieces separated by fieldsep and store the pieces in array and the separator strings in the seps array. **The first piece is stored in array[1]**, the second piece in array[2], and so forth. The string value of the third argument, fieldsep, is a regexp describing where to split string (much as FS can be a regexp describing where to split input records; see Regexp Field Splitting). If fieldsep is omitted, the value of FS is used. split() returns the number of elements created. seps is a gawk extension with seps[i] being the separator string between array[i] and array[i+1]. If fieldsep is a single space then any leading whitespace goes into seps[0] and any trailing whitespace goes into seps[n] where n is the return value of split() (that is, the number of elements in array).